# Cannot create a new react project

Tags: javascript, reactjs, terminal, project

when ı try to create  new react project with "npx create-react-app my-app" this command ı only see that screen below. have any ideas how can ı fix it, and make terminal keep installing instead stopping at this point.[bug](https://i.stack.imgur.com/0PcxQ.png)

Comment: What happens if you just keep waiting? Leave it in the background.

Answer (score 0):

Try uninstalling any global installations of `create-react-app` with `npm uninstall -g create-react-app` and then run the command again.